# Python add and get magic (dunder) methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, magic-methods

I have run into an issue regarding Python dunder methods. There is a class that represents a number, however I want to built in some restrictions to the arithmetic of that represented number. So I have the followin:

```
class Property:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return instance.value
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        # Implement some arithmetic boundaries
        instance.value
    def __add__(self, other):
        # Implement arithmetic boundaries
        self.value += other
    def __sub__(self, other):
        etc..
```

Now this won't work. If I create an instance and try to add to that value like so:

```
p = Property(0)
p + 5
p = 6
```

P will not be of type property anymore, instead an int. I'd like to combine all these dunder methods. But it does not seem possible.

Comment: to add in place I believe you want to implement the method that supports `+=` e.g. `__iadd__()`. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__ you're welcome =) @Athylus

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue you describe. When I run the exact code you show in your example, I see `p.value` as equal to 5. I suspect you're actually doing something else, and in simplifying the code for the example, you've edited out the issue you're running into.

Comment: yeah.. @Blckknght is right. the code will work the way you have it. But it's more along the lines of expected behavior to implement the in-place operations with the += (`__iadd__()`) operator. for the regular `__add__()` operation, you should return another Property object with its value set to 5 for example.

Comment: Thanks @Todd. However, I still cannot set my variable that way. Let me update my question. Also using iadd and p += 1 sets it to none?

Comment: Can you post the code that is dealing with the object? I notice that in your `__set__()` method, you aren't setting the variable. You only have `instance.value` your code works for me and the other poster, so this doesn't make sense.